# Spring boot autowiring BeanCreationException for static field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having an issue when I am autowiring my properties class.

The following is my properties class which behaves fine when I autowire it in my @service class.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RefreshScope
public class SMSHistoryProperties {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    /**
     * Return the property value associated with the given key, or null if the
     * key cannot be resolved.
     * 
     * @param propName
     * @return
     */ 
    public String getProperty(String propName){     
        return env.getProperty(propName);
    }
```

but when I autowire it in my SQLConstants class (which only has static constant variables) I am getting an exception.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vzw.onem.search.properties.SMSHistoryProperties;

@Component
public class SQLConstants {

    @Autowired
    private static SMSHistoryProperties prop;

    //~ Static fields/initializers ------------------------------------------

    private static final String SMS_SCHEMA = prop.getProperty("sms.schema");
```

---

The exception I get is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'SQLConstants' defined in file
[...\SQLConstants.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [com.search.constants.SQLConstants]: Constructor
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

EDIT:

I took the static final reference out but I am still getting a null pointer exception.

```
@Autowired
private SMSHistoryProperties prop;

private String BATCH_SMS_SQL = "SELECT ACK_CODE FROM "
            + prop.getProperty("sms.schema");
```

The `nullpointer` is occurring on `prop.getProperty("sms.schema")`.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'SMSController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'smsBuilder'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'SMSBuilder': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'searchHelper'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'smsJdbcSearchHelper': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'cccDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'smsSearchDAOImpl' defined in file
>   [..\SmsSearchDAOImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [com.vzw.onem.search.dao.impl.SmsSearchDAOImpl]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can you post more of the stacktrace ? and the relevant code

Comment: You will be much better off providing the autowired items as constructor parameters (much less to go wrong), and in this case just use `@Value("${sms.schema}") String schema` as a constructor parameter instead of pulling it from the environment manually.

Comment: @chrylis But pulling it from the environment is more ideal isn't it? If you do it with the Value annotation then you will have flooded your application with properties annotations

Comment: @Robin You already "flood" you application with that same information inside your `getProperty` call, you just move it further away and make it difficult to override (e.g., for testing). It's better to expose explicitly that "bean foo needs these two values" than to say "bean foo gets the env and pulls some unspecified information from it".

Comment: @chrylis I maybe misunderstanding you can you elaborate. If i stay with the environment approach then I will just have to use `getProperty(value)` instead of having field variables annotated with Value. Why would the environment way be less ideal than explicitly calling it with the value annotation.

Comment: Because using `@Value` (preferably on constructor parameters, not fields) is *directly* connecting the relationship between the particular piece of data and the class's API, while using the environment hides exactly what data you need. A helpful guideline: If you want to insert test values with String constructor parameters, you just have to call `new MyService(string1, string2)`. If you want to do it with the indirect method, you have to mock up `Environment` (and duplicate your property keys).

Comment: @chrylis I see, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could not make your `static` fields with initializer that depend on a spring bean as beans are initialized only after the instantiation of the class by Spring while the `static` field is initialized before any instantiation of the class.

Instead make these fields instance fields and use `@PostConstruct` to init constant values after the dependency injection was done.

```
@Component
public class SQLConstants {

   @Autowired
   private SMSHistoryProperties prop;

   //~ Static fields/initializers ------------------------------------------

   private String SMS_SCHEMA; 

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
        SMS_SCHEMA = prop.getProperty("sms.schema"); 
   }
}
```

Consequently, you could not keep them `final` field.  But you can guarantee that these be not updated from client classes by not providing setters for them.   Which may be an acceptable workaround.

An alternative 1, inject directly the values in the String fields such as :

```
private final String schema;   

public SQLConstants(@Value("${sms.schema}")String schema){
    this.schema = schema;
}
```

or :

```
@Value("${sms.schema}")
private String schema;
```

The field injection way is shorter but makes the class API less testable without a Spring container and the field cannot be `final` either.

An alternative 2 (my preference for your use case) make `SMSHistoryProperties` less generic by providing methods for each value that you need to retrieve. It eliminate the needs to declare String constants and it will make your code more meaningful.
You could also unit test each retrieval method to ensure no regression issues if properties are changed.

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class SMSHistoryProperties {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public String getSchema(){     
        return env.getProperty("sms.schema");
    }

    public String getOtherValue(){     
        return env.getProperty("sms.otherValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i will most likely do it with the getters as you suggested in the bottom

Comment: Actually i still get nullpointer even when I remove the static reference.

Comment: FWIW, you can't use `final` with the field injection (one more reason to prefer the constructor).

Comment: @chrylis Completely right (I was not sure about it). Thanks for this improvement.

Comment: @Robin I think that you probably has another issue. Does the `NullPointerException` refers to the same line in the source code ? If it is the case, ensure that you posted exactly your actually code. Otherwise which statement does the exception refer to ? You can post to pastebin.com if it makes sense.

Comment: @davidxxx I have updated to include the change and exception. also i tried going into pastebin but my company blocks that site.

Comment: According to your stacktrace, the issue is in the `SmsSearchDAOImpl` classloading or instantiation. Check if you use initializer or static fields that may cause the issue. I am surprised that Spring doesn't provide the exact line where the NPE occurs. It should I think.

Comment: I figured it out. It was due to trying to instantiate the prop into an instance field. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't `Autowired` static field in `Spring`. So, Your `SMSHistoryProperties prop` will set to `null`. And you are using `prop` to call `getProperty("sms.schema");` and obviously, it will give you `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I still get nullpointer even when I remove the static reference.